# df -h doesn't show /dev/sda

Tags: disk, df

I am using `df -h` to get my disk space and the results are:

```
Filesystem     Size       Used     Avail  Use%   Mounted on
udev            2.0G       4.0K     2.0G   1%     /dev
tmpfs           396M       436K     395M   1%     /run
/dev/vda1       59G        3.6G     53G    7%     /
none            4.0K       0        4.0K   0%     /sys/fs/cgroup
none            5.0M       0        5.0M   0%     /run/lock
none            2.0G       12K      2.0G   1%     /run/shm
none            100M       12K      100M   1%     /run/user
```

and when I use `sudo fdisk -l | grep Disk` , I get:

```
Disk /dev/vda: 64.4 GB, 64424509440 bytes
Disk /dev/sda: 107.4 GB, 107374182400 bytes
```

Why doesn't `df -h` doesn't show space on `/dev/sda`? How can I see my total Disk space?

Comment: Does `/dev/sda` have any mounted partitions?

Comment: Please show the list of partitions from `fdisk`, your `grep` is too mean.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`df` only cares about (mounted) filesystem, not any raw disk/partition.

If you follow the standard procedure to make a raw disk available to be used by userspace processes i.e. partition the device `/dev/sda`, and then format them using desired filesystem, and mount the filesystems, then the filesystems would obviously be shown by `df`.

Comment: hmm....I can see now partition is not mounted.I am getting a message `Disk /dev/sda doesn't contain a valid partition table`. Let me see how can I add it to my filesystem

Comment: Is there any link avilable for how can I mount this sda partition?

Comment: just run `udisksctl mount -b /dev/sda1` That'll do everything automatically for you and tell you which folder it's mounted to, which typically is under /media/username/partitionID

Comment: I am getting `Error looking up object for device /dev/sda1`

Comment: @PrashantPrabhakarSingh what does lsblk tell you ? is there only /dev/sda or are there devices with numbers ? have you tried the command with /dev/sda ?

Comment: as the OP is likely a beginner, maybe precise that usually he will mount one of the partitions of sda, so for example : `mount /dev/sda1  /somewhere`  (ie, he will rarely see "/dev/sda" mounted, but "/dev/sdaX")

Comment: I am a beginner to this and have no idea what's going on. The O/P of `lsblk` is   `sda       8:0    0   100G  0 disk  
vda     253:0    0    60G  0 disk  \u251c\u2500vda1  253:1    0    60G  0 part / \u2514\u2500vda15 253:15   0     1M  0 pa`

Comment: @PrashantPrabhakarSingh Please ask this as a [new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with all the details.

Comment: I have asked a [new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/841497/how-to-mount-a-partition). Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

To know the total disk space you could do something like this:

```
dmesg | grep sda
```

On my system it prints several lines. The interesting one is:

```
[19266.419331] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 272629760 512-byte logical blocks: (139 GB/130 GiB)
```

In this case, the size is 139 GB.