# How to mount a partition?

Tags: partitioning, mount

I am new to Linux and don't know anything about mounting. This question is related to [df -h doesn't show /dev/sda](https://askubuntu.com/questions/841160/df-h-doesnt-show-dev-sda/841174?noredirect=1#comment1288540_841174). What comments teach me is the partition is not mounted. So, how to do that, since I have no idea of it. I am scared of damaging something accidentally.

Output of `lsblk` is :

```
NAME    MAJ:MIN  RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
 sda        8:0    0   100G  0 disk
 vda      253:0    0    60G  0 disk 
  vda1    253:1    0    60G  0 part /
  vda15   253:15   0     1M  0 part
```

The o/P of `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda` is:

> Disk /dev/sda: 107.4 GB, 107374182400 bytes
>  255 heads, 63
>   sectors/track, 13054 cylinders, total 209715200 sectors
>  Units =
>   sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512
>   bytes / 512 bytes 
> I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>   Disk identifier: 0x727b8bb7
>
> Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System

I don't understand why the 100G of sda isn't available. If I have to mount it then HOW?

Comment: What does `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda` or `sudo parted -l /dev/sda` report?

Comment: I have modified the ques with o/p of  `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/dev/sda` is a disk, not a partition. A partition identifier contains a number, e.g. `/dev/sda1`. It looks like you have no partitions on your `sda` drive. You have to create at least one partition on the empty disk, format it and then mount.

There is a well-written guide at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingANewHardDrive mentioning all the options, just follow it carefully.

Answer (score 1):

The name `/dev/sda` represents the first HDD in your system. If you had to hard disk drives in your system, the next one would be called `/dev/sdb` and so on. However, when ever you use your computer to access files, to install operating systems, to manipulate and/or store files on your hard disk, you are actually manipulating "Partitions" instead of the entirety of the disk. Partitions are portions of the hard disk i.e. `/dev/sda` which have a starting point and ending point and each partition has it's own filesystem which in layman's terms is a table which contains the name of the file and the starting and ending addresses of the bits that comprise the file.

Now partitions have a similar nomenclature as disks but, they have a number at the end of each name. for example, the first partition of the first hard disk of your system might be called `/dev/sda1`. Now if you are coming to linux from windows you probably know this process as "formatting a disk". But in linux, to make your disk ready for use, you have first to create a partition table on your disk. [to learn how to create a GPT partition table on your disk using gparted, read the guide on this link](http://akabaila.pcug.org.au/gpt/gpt_gparted.html) . After creating the GPT partition table(scheme) - or an MSDOS one if you prefer - you need to create a partition on the disk. Just follow the guide I have linked above for the creating a partition table and follow the steps I have listed below to create a partition, a filesystem and mount the filesystem. Notice what I just said, ONE MOUNTS A FIELSYSTEM - NOT A PARTITION.

**1. Creating a Partition**

To create a partition, click on the Partition menu of the Gparted window and Choose "New"

[image]

after doing so just click on add on the next windows that pops up.

[image]

then go to the "edit" menu of the gparted window and click on "Apply All Operations" then follow that with a click on "Apply" on the confirmation windows that pops up next. You now have a partition table, a partition and a filesystem. To mount the filesystem, you can just click on the new "100 GB Volume" addition to the left hand side of your file manager's window.